# How to disable Android Studio 3.5 sorting xml tags alphabetically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When formatting an xml file like a layout file, AS 3.5 started sorting tags alphabetically. It's rudely aweful, how do I turn it off?

Comment: this already has an answer :)

Answer (score -2):

On a Mac, you can go to Preferences -> Code Style -> XML. Item number 7 is the filter for "all tags", and says to sort alphabetically. Click edit, disable the sort.